# How to implement Custom channel notifications in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to write my custom laravel channel notifications, like this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/notifications#custom-channels.

I wrote this code:

AimonChannel.php

```
class AimonChannel{
public function send($notifiable, Notification $notification)
  {

    $message = $notification->toAimon($notifiable);
    if (is_string($message)) {
      $message = new AimonMessage($message);
    }
    //some code to send sms with curl

}
```

AimonMessage.php

```
class AimonMessage
{

  public $messaggio = "";

  public function messaggio($messaggio){
    $this->messaggio = $messaggio;
  }

}
```

SendAimonMessage.php

```
class SendAimonMessage extends Notification
{
  use Queueable;
  protected $messaggio;

public function __construct($messaggio)
  {
    $this->messaggio = $messaggio;
  }

public function via($notifiable)
  {
    return [AimonChannel::class];
  }

public function toAimon($notifiable)
  {

    return (new AimonMessage())
    ->messaggio($this->messaggio);
  }
}
```

So, the code:

```
$user->notify(new SendAimonMessage('my custom message'));
```

is sent, but without the text. 
The problem is in the send() function of AimonChannel; the $message variable is always null.
Where is my code mistake?
Thanks!

Comment: try this,  public function toAimon($notifiable)
  {

    return $this->messaggio;
  }

Comment: Perfect! The error was in is_string() function. AimonMessage isn't a string!

Answer (score 0):

add return statement in the messaggio function like this:

```
class AimonMessage {

    public $messaggio = "";
    public function messaggio($messaggio){ 
        $this->messaggio = $messagio;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Even if this solves the answer, can you please explain how and why?